# ".java is not on the classpath of project, it will not be compiled to a .class file" error

Tags: java, github

I made 3 Java files and uploaded them to a git repository. I then cloned that repository onto VS Code and it linked up perfectly.

After committing and pushing my first version, it came up with the error mentioned in the title on every Java file.

(Let me know if you need any more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add environment variables for java and also ensure that you have added that Java to your IDE. Most probably its not selected that's why you are seeing this error.